# Activate two devices with a DPDT switch and two relays

Tags: switches, relay, automotive, dpdt

I'm working on an automotive project. I have an electric water pump and fan, both of which will be powered through relays. I also have an on-off-on dpdt switch. What I'd like to achieve is activating the pump at both poles and just the fan at the other. This seems doable, but in all my attempts I've only been able to have both on or both off. How do I wire the switch to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a diode.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7yZ7y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Do you have a 3 position switch ON-OFF-ON and two diodes?

Comment: Not one of the available schematic symbols. It isn't significant in any case, the switch is DPDT when in one of the two "on" positions.

Comment: drive both coils with 1 diode drop for each coil from ON-1 and drive one coil from ON-2.  Then add reverse diodes across each coil for snubbers.  so 4 diodes. centre pole=12V fused. only need SPDT

Comment: Ah, okay. I was thinking to myself, "I feel like there's something out there that only allows the current to flow in one direction." Now I know my hunch was right, but more importantly what it is I need.

Comment: As @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 mentioned, reverse diodes on the coils is a good idea. I'll add them to the schematic.

Comment: Sounds like I could use a DPDT switch with one diode, or a SPDT with four diodes. I'd like to keep it as simple as possible, so I think I'll try the single diode approach first. How do I know which diode I need for this project? It's just your typical 12v DC automotive electrical system.

Comment: Don't kid yourself, you need 3 unless your relays are internally protected. Only 1 diode is used for the relay power selection, the other two are circuit protection (don't skimp, diodes are cheap). You can use either an SPDT or DPDT switch (but you'll only use 1/2 of it), so if you have a DPDT on hand, just use it. As far as which diode, 1n4007 should be fine. Don't forget to mark the question as an answer.

Comment: they cant use reverse diodes in cars, but you can if you need  EMI reduction, but twisted pairs for all cable in absence of a metal chassis ground plane, unless EMI pulse is ok.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2cVtg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This was what I had in mind for EMI control of Pump glitches which are probably worse than relay coil glitches.

- no transistor protection needed if battery nearby.
- Battery cables are twisted as well for EMI control.
- Avoid large current loop area with paired wires or twisted wires

  - (Pwr/Return)

> Although it may not matter in your application but for cars , they have to survive reverse jump cables and 2xVbat jump cables **so reverse diodes are *verbotten* as they would blow. So, they use Snubber power resistors, often inbuilt.**

[image]

Comment: This is the type of automotive relay I'm using in my project: !(https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/410SFrIB44L.jpg) !(https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/410SFrIB44L.jpg)

Comment: as I suspected , so no reverse diodes on coil needed, but load may have arcs

Comment: Okay, so just the one diode on the trigger feed then?

Comment: Yes the one diode isolates the pair of relays for just the Fan. In logic , we call this Diode OR logic. The relay coil has a wide operating  range, so  the diode drop is neglible whether it is 0.3V Schottky or 0.7V Silicon, won't matter.  I would choose Silicon for greater PIV with snubber R built in, I am not certain of value hence spike voltage but Silicon 1N4005 .. no sweat